# Oracle duplicate record deletion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with main fields

ArticleNo,Barcode,UnitOfMeasure etc

How i can remove the duplicate records from the table if articleno and barcode and unitofmeasure are same

Trying to remove the duplicate records from oracle table

Comment: Please provide some sample data and what you have tried so far

Comment: The straight-forward approach in my opinion: delete from the table where `EXISTS` a duplicate. (And in order not to remove the original along with its duplicate you use the primary key or rowid, i.e. "where exists a duplicate with a lower id").

Answer (score 0):

Usual way of doing it is

```
delete from your_table a
where a.rowid > (select min(b.rowid)
                 from your_table b
                 where a.articleno = b.articleno
                   and a.barcode = b.barcode
                   and a.unitofmeasure = b.unitofmeasure);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usally do this by filtering the MIN or MAX rowids for the given combinations:

```
DELETE 
  FROM some_table
 WHERE ROWID NOT IN (
                     SELECT rid
                       FROM (
                             SELECT MIN(rowid) as rid, ArticleNo, Barcode, UnitOfMeasure
                               FROM some_table 
                              GROUP BY ArticleNo, Barcode, UnitOfMeasure
                            )
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Which row do you want to keep? In the example below I use the `lag()` function to find all "previous" rows in order of unit_of_measure, so we keep only the max unit_of_measure for each article_no/barcode combination.

Sample data:

```
create table sometable (article_no,barcode,unit_of_measure)
as
select 1, 12345, 'Litre' from dual union all
select 1, 12345, 'Pint' from dual union all
select 2, 34567, 'Gallon' from dual union all
select 2, 34567, 'Fluid Ounce' from dual union all
select 3, 45678, 'Quart' from dual union all
select 3, 45678, 'Bushel' from dual;
```

| ARTICLE_NO | BARCODE | UNIT_OF_MEASURE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Litre |
| 1 | 12345 | Pint |
| 2 | 34567 | Fluid Ounce |
| 2 | 34567 | Gallon |
| 3 | 45678 | Bushel |
| 3 | 45678 | Quart |

```
delete sometable where rowid in
( select lag(rowid) over (
           partition by article_no,barcode
           order by unit_of_measure
         )
  from   sometable );
```

Now table contains:

| ARTICLE_NO | BARCODE | UNIT_OF_MEASURE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | Pint |
| 2 | 34567 | Gallon |
| 3 | 45678 | Quart |

Answer (score 0):

Just Run the query it will delete your duplicate data.

```
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT 
            ArticleNo, 
            Barcode, 
            UnitOfMeasure, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY 
                    ArticleNo, 
            Barcode, 
            UnitOfMeasure
                ORDER BY 
                    ArticleNo, 
            Barcode, 
            UnitOfMeasure
            ) row_num
         FROM 
            your_table
    )
    DELETE FROM cte
    WHERE row_num > 1
```